# QML access to ListView custom property from header component

Tags: qml, qmllint

I have code like this (reusable `LisView`):

```js
//ListViewEx.qml

ListView {
    id: root
    property string headerText

    header: Pane {
        id: headerComponent
        ...
        Label {
            text: root.headerText
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and use it, like this:

```js
//sample.qml

Item {
    ...
    Pane {
        ...
        GridLayout {
            ...
            ListViewEx {
                headerText: qsTr('sample header')
                ...
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

This works, but `qmllint` reports "Unqualified access". I'm new to QML and I'm not sure if it's a problem with `qmllint` or should I use different formule.

I tried some modification. For example text binding like this:

```js
    text: headerComponent.ListView.view.headerText
```

This works too, but `qmllint` reports "Property headerText not found on type QQuickItemView".
Interestingly, in the first case, if I change the `ListView` property declaration to this (which is obviously a bug - required properties with initializer do not make sense):

```
    required property string headerText: ""
```

then `qllint` will stop reporting the warning.

========

- Python 3.11
- PySide6 (Qt 6.4.1)
- VSCode

Comment: I see that this question is about best practices and working on producing correct `qmllint`-able code.

Comment: @StephenQuan qmllint-able code can [have better preformance](https://www.qt.io/blog/compiling-qml-to-c-fixing-unqualfied-access).

Comment: I think you would have to expose some property on your model and register it in the typesystem..

Comment: @ניר can you explain how, where in the OP's code there is (1) poor performance, (2) where in the OP code is there a model that needs to be registered? The OP even supplied a workaround to the qmllint issue, and, can you clarify how that workaround improves poor performance?

Comment: @StephenQuan 1. I didn't say that there is poor preformance, just that qmllinted code can complie to C++ better.  2. If the model for the view is from C++ you could register its properties via the [qml type registration system](https://www.qt.io/blog/qml-type-registration-in-qt-5.15) and then If he would put the `headerText` as a `property` of the model qmllint would be satisfied I think.

Comment: @ניר I still cannot understand why you insist that the `headerText` should be in the model. The `headerText` never appears in the item delegate at all. Its usage is in the header delegate which has no connection to the model. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html#header-prop

Comment: @StephenQuan Not necessarily the model but In some qmlregistered type...  I usually put them close to the model. usually the model is exposed from C++ via context property or some singletone instance...

Comment: @ניר I'm using Python and PySide6 not C++. Unfortunately qmllint can't see types registered via qmlRegisterXXX calls. Is it different with C++?

Comment: You can declare them in [qmldir](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html#object-type-declaration) I think though I havn't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can consider using the `ListView.view` attached property to gain access to the parent `ListView`. Typically, in a delegate, I assigned the attached property to a new property so that the entire delegate has a convenient way of accessing the property:

```
property ListView listView: ListView.view
```

The following is an example usage where both the item delegate and header delegate are using the `ListView.view` attached property to discover its `width` as well as read the custom `headerText` property:

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    MyListView {
        width: 200
        height: parent.height
        headerText: qsTr('sample header')
        model: MyModel { }
        delegate: MyDelegate { }
    }
}

// MyListView.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
ListView {
    model: 20
    width: 200
    height: parent.height
    property string headerText: "Header"
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
        width: 20
        policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
    }
    header: MyHeader { }
}

// MyHeader.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Frame {
    property ListView listView: ListView.view
    width: listView.width - 20
    background: Rectangle {
        color: index & 1 ? "#eee" : "#ddd"
        border.color: "#ccc"
    }
    Text {
        text: listView.headerText
    }
}

// MyDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Frame {
    property ListView listView: ListView.view
    width: listView.width - 20
    background: Rectangle {
        color: index & 1 ? "#eee" : "#ddd"
        border.color: "#ccc"
    }
    RowLayout {
        width: parent.width
        Text {
            text: index + 1
            color: "grey"
        }
        Text {
            text: n
        }
    }
}

// MyModel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
ListModel {
    ListElement { n: "Bill Gates" }
    ListElement { n: "Jeff Bezos" }
    ListElement { n: "Steve Jobs" }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Indeed, your method is convenient and shortens the code. However, it does not suppress qmllint warnings. After refactoring it reports "Property headerText not found on type QQuickItemView". I'm starting to think that qmllint is still quite a primitive tool. It also report warnings that are confusing. For example, using role names in a ListView delegate without using the required property. The use of the proposal to define such properties changes the behavior of the delegate, which is intentional and documented behavior.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. I am sorry the suggestion didn't work with qmllint. :-(